# MS Project Pro 2019 & MS Office Home and Business 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-project

I was able to download Project 2019 via Office Deployment Tool (ODT) and were able to install it to one workstation who also has a Click-to-Run Office installed.

The **Project 2019** was able to run without any error, however whenever I try to open any of the **Office Home and Business 2013** applications it gives me the ***"First things first."*** pop-up where I need to click 'Agree' to proceed.

The problems are
i.) If I click 'Agree', office application closes/crashes.
ii.) If I click 'View Agreement', office application closes/crashes.

Bottomline, **Office 2013** cannot be used anymore.
So I uninstalled **Project 2019** to revert everything back.

Questions: Anyone here knows the reason why it happens? Is it compatibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since Office 2013 Home and Business and Project 2019 both use Click-to-Run,  and there is no overlap in applications, I think they can be installed together. You can review this article: [Supported scenarios for installing different versions of Office, Project, and Visio on the same computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer)

Please note:

1. Even though a particular installation scenario is supported, it might not be recommended. Because there may be some weird.
2. All installed products must be either the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version.

I also suggest you update both Office 2013 and Project 2019 to the latest. Or try repairing Office 2013. Please refer to [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried to repair Office 2013 from Control Panel but that didn't work as well. Now I will try to install Project 2019 again and see if same thing will happen, hopefully not. If Office will still crash, I will use the "SetupProd_OffScrub" that I have downloaded from your link to repair Office. Thanks, I'll update the result later.

Comment: Office 2013 is still crashing. I tried using the "SetupProd_OffScrub" but it's asking me to uninstall Office 2013. I canceled it because I don't want to uninstall the Office because I don't have the Product Key for it. And then I tried to "Repair Online " via control Panel, but it asks me to restart first. Unfortunately after restarting, both Office 2013 and Project 2019 is gone T_T. So currently I am performing system restore from september 12. If ever the system restore fails, I'm not sure if I will still be able to reinstall Office 2013. I'm currently in deep shit T_T.

Comment: @Tim.Towers, I really don't realize that you don't have a product key. Please refer to the [link1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2016-or-office-2013-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479#InstallSteps=Office_2013_for_PC) and [link2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/reinstall-office-home-business-2013/4312efa8-e3e1-47f5-a2e5-6d4a6eadf755) to see if it helps:

Comment: I found the key for Office 2013, the previous IT kept it in one file. But then I installed different product key 'Office Home & Business 2016' which is both a Click-to-Run and version 16. However, when I tried to install Project 2019 again it's asking me to uninstall Office 2016. Now I don't know which Office are really compatible with Project 2019. Should I just install Project 2016 and use the MAK provided at VLSC, will that be possible?